# Indeterminate QProgressBar inside QListWidget

Tags: qt, qlistwidget, qprogressbar

as stand in the OP title, is there any chance to get an indeterminate `QProgressBar` indide a `QListWidget`?

```
    bar = new QProgressBar();   
    bar->setMinimum(0);
    bar->setMaximum(0);
    QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem ;
    list->setItemWidget(item, bar);
    list->setCurrentRow(0);
```

that's what I tried but it displays nothing? Any hint?

thank you:

EDIT: I need to wait results from a long term procedure and I want to show the results inside the QListWidget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the parent of `ProgressBar` to `list`.

Instead of bar = new QProgressBar();

Use  `bar = new QProgressBar(list);`

That would do.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I recive the first item from my long term procedure, I want to remove the QProgressBar and add the item. I tried the QListWidget::removeItemWidget(item), but bar is still there. Any hint?

Comment: For removing the item, you have to delete the item. so do "delete bar" when you wish to remove the itemwidget. Qt Documentation says so..

Comment: Could you please point me out the link where the doc says so? +1 anyway